# Swift 2.0 / iOS 9 Compatibilities

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compatibility

I have a few issues concerning the recent addition of Swift 2.0 and upcoming iOS9.

Currently I have been working on an app that works with iOS7 or above, and using Swift 1.2 things...nothing that Swift 2 has.  I was told that I should start updating everything to include Swift 2 rather than the older ways of using Swift.  So my questions are...

1)  If I do begin to work with Swift 2 code, will iOS 7 and iOS 8 be able to recognize that code, or does Swift 2 only work with certain versions of iOS?

2)  If I choose NOT to work with the Swift 2 code and stick with what I have that works already for iOS 7 and 8, is it possible that in iOS9 or later, it won't work because it expects Swift 2 and it's not getting it?

I have looked for compatibility articles and answers online and found nothing.  The only thing I've learned is that Swift 2 just adds code, and doesn't necessarily change anything...so maybe just keeping my old code would be okay.  But again I'm not exactly sure.  Thanks.

Comment: 1) Swift 2 will work on iOS 7 and 8.  You can verify that yourself by testing on the older emulators.  2) Apps compiled with Swift 1.2 will work on future iOS releases, otherwise Apple would break apps that are already in the store, and that isn't in their best interest.  Note that the apps are compiled, so the language features are pretty much gone by the time the binary is created, so it isn't a matter of which version of the non-compiled language iOS is expecting.

Comment: You can't submit apps written in Swift 2 until Xcode 7 is out of beta.  Who knows exactly when that will be, but if history is a guide, it will be out around the time iOS 9 is released.  Late September, maybe.

Comment: If you decide to migrate to Xcode 7/Swift 2, keep a copy of your project still in Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.4.  The migration only goes 1 direction, so if you change your mind, it is really hard to convert Swift 2 code back to Swift 1.2.  Apple provides no migration help in that direction.

Comment: Apple recommends (requires?) that you use the latest released version of Xcode when submitting apps to the app store.  So, after Xcode 7 is released, you should move to Swift 2.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will work as far back as iOS 7 for right now, regardless of what version of Swift you are using. As far as whether you should update your code, that's up to you, but of course Swift 2.0 does offer a lot more in terms of safety and error checking so if you find situations where it would be pertinent to implement such new features, then you probably should. Also some syntax is different, but if you update now you'll just be future-proofing yourself.

Comment: As far as deploying back to iOS 7, you can quote Joe Groff, one of the compiler engineers: ["Swift 2 will deploy back to iOS 7 and 10.9."](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/609380712492314624) . About as definitive a reference as you can get.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had heard him say that but I couldn't find it.